# Screen Flickers to Mouse Cursor

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, screen, flicker

I have Lubuntu 16.04. It is running on a Thinkpad X201 using Intel graphics devices (no Nvidia here).

After I watch a video on Youtube or use `mplayer` to watch a video, the screen flickers black right up to where my mouse cursor is.

It looks like [this](https://youtu.be/xQIRVQneHGc).

Logging out and logging back in resolves the issue.

Update: This only occurs when the mouse cursor is more than about an inch from the right hand side of the screen.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

fixed the issue for me.

However, now the mouse cursor disappears when waking from sleep. I haven't found a fix for this, but a work-around is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: The second thing you mention here has stopped the flickering and is a quick fix... I installed the package, and if I never see the flickering again, I will try to remember to report back. Thanks.

Comment: That's totally weired! I solved a flickering problem by removing xorg intel drive

Comment: @AntonioMolinaro: The plot thickened... and then it congealed. Super weird.

Comment: Running this command crashed my OS. I can no longer reach the login screen.